Variable set in MDC is not accessible in log4j2
I have a spring MVC project( not a springboot ). I am trying to use MDC to add traceId for logging(MDC.set("X_REQUEST_ID",uuid.randomuuid().tostring()). Now I have added the code to set a variable(X_REQUEST_ID) in my Filter class. And in the log4j2.xml i have added the pattern as
%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS} [%X{X_REQUEST_ID}] [%t] %-5p %c

But When I run the project its printing [ ] for X_REQUEST_ID that means there is no value.
I have test the code but using MDC.get("X_REQUEST_ID") And its properly set and visible as in the code.
I am using org.apache.log4j.MDC and below are my dependencies.
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
    </dependency>


You are using the wrong API: org.apache.log4j.MDC is a Log4j 1 class and it is only used by Log4j 1.
What you need to use is org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext (see documentation):
try {
    ThreadContext.put("X_REQUEST_ID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    // your code
} finally {
    ThreadContext.remove("X_REQUEST_ID");
}

Remark: You might consider using the log4j-1.2-api bridge (cf. migration), which will forward MDC calls to ThreadContext calls, but MDC is usually used so few times, that it is not worth an additional dependency.
